# What is the difference between jQuery version 1, version 2, and version 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently stumbled upon a page `webchart.js` design  using jQuery version 2, and I am using jQuery version 1.

For the code to work see to it to use now the latest version, then I checked jQuery core support and they have jQuery 3 released.

I am thinking of using version 3 now, but I am looking for if version 3 has compatibility issues, that it may only be used on specific devices.

Answer (score 275, accepted):

**Major Versions**

Version 1.0: First stable release.
Version 2.0: Dropped IE 6–8 support for performance improvements and reduction in filesize
Version 3.0: [Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/) support for Deferreds, `$.ajax` and `$.when`, `.data()` HTML5-compatible

**All Versions**

```
+----------------+--------------------+----------------------------+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Version Number |    Release Date    |       Latest Update        | Size Prod (KB) |                                   Additional Notes                                    |
+----------------+--------------------+----------------------------+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1.0            | August 26, 2006    |                            |                | First stable release                                                                  |
| 1.1            | January 14, 2007   |                            |                |                                                                                       |
| 1.2            | September 10, 2007 | 1.2.6                      | 54             |                                                                                       |
| 1.3            | January 14, 2009   | 1.3.2                      | 55.9           | Sizzle Selector Engine introduced into core                                           |
| 1.4            | January 14, 2010   | 1.4.4                      | 76             |                                                                                       |
| 1.5            | January 31, 2011   | 1.5.2                      | 83             | Deferred callback management, ajax module rewrite                                     |
| 1.6            | May 3, 2011        | 1.6.4                      | 89             | Significant performance improvements to the attr() and val() functions                |
| 1.7            | November 3, 2011   | 1.7.2 (March 21, 2012)     | 92             | New Event APIs: .on() and .off(), while the old APIs are still supported.             |
| 1.8            | August 9, 2012     | 1.8.3 (November 13, 2012)  | 91.4           | Sizzle Selector Engine rewritten, improved animations and $(html, props) flexibility. |
| 1.9            | January 15, 2013   | 1.9.1 (February 4, 2013)   | 90             | Removal of deprecated interfaces and code cleanup                                     |
| 1.10           | May 24, 2013       | 1.10.2 (July 3, 2013)      | 91             | Incorporated bug fixes and differences reported from both the 1.9 and 2.0 beta cycles |
| 1.11           | January 24, 2014   | 1.11.3 (April 28, 2015)    | 95.9           |                                                                                       |
| 1.12           | January 8, 2016    | 1.12.4 (May 20, 2016)      | 95             |                                                                                       |
| 2.0            | April 18, 2013     | 2.0.3 (July 3, 2013)       | 81.1           | Dropped IE 6–8 support for performance improvements and reduction in filesize         |
| 2.1            | January 24, 2014   | 2.1.4 (April 28, 2015)     | 82.4           |                                                                                       |
| 2.2            | January 8, 2016    | 2.2.4 (May 20, 2016)       | 85.6           |                                                                                       |
| 3.0            | June 9, 2016       | 3.0.0 (June 9, 2016)       | 86.3           | Promises/A+ support for Deferreds, $.ajax and $.when, .data() HTML5-compatible        |
| 3.1            | July 7, 2016       | 3.1.1 (September 23, 2016) | 86.3           | jQuery.readyException added, ready handler errors are now not silenced                |
| 3.2            | March 16, 2017     | 3.2.1 (March 20, 2017)     | 84.6           | Hotfixes for regressions that were introduced in the 3.2.0                            |
| 3.3            | January 19, 2018   | 3.3.1 (January 20, 2018)   | 84.8           | Deprecation of old function calls, functions that accept classes now support them     |
|                |                    |                            |                | defined in an array                                                                   |
| 3.4            | April 10, 2019     | 3.4.1 (May 1, 2019)        | 86.1           | Performance improvements, nonce and nomodule support, fixes for radio elements, a     |
|                |                    |                            |                | minor security fix                                                                    |
| 3.5            | April 10, 2020     | 3.5.1 (May 4, 2020)        | 87.4           | Security fixes, .even() & .odd() methods, jQuery.trim deprecated                      |
| 3.6            | March 2, 2021      | 3.6.0 (March 2, 2021)      | 90.0           | Bug fixes, return JSON when there is a JSONP error                                    |
+----------------+--------------------+----------------------------+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery#Release_history

**Detailed Explanation on Major Versions**

Version 1.0 was the first stable release of jQuery. This release supports older web browsers that aren't even supported by their respective developers any longer. If you expect a large amount of visitors with older web browsers, this would definitely be the version to go for.

Versions 2.0 dropped support for Internet Explorer 6-8 to increase jQuery's overall performance and reduce the library's filesize. In simple words: Version 2.0 is faster and smaller in filesize than version 1.0, but it no longer supports older web browsers. Since Microsoft dropped the support for Windows XP, it's reasonably safe to assume that your visitors will be using a browser compatibile with version 2.0 unless you know beforehand this won't be the case (see version 1.0).

With the release of version 3.0 both versions 1.11.1 and 2.1.1 will be upgraded to jQuery Compat 3.0 and jQuery 3.0. jQuery Compat 3.0 will still support older browsers like Internet Explorer 8 while the regular version 3.0 will only support evergreen browsers (the current and previous versions of a specific browser).

With the release of Version 3.0 there's no reason to stick to either version 1.0 or 2.0. A few notes from the official jQuery blog:

> - If you need support for the widest variety of browsers including IE8,
>   Opera 12, Safari 5, and the like, use the jQuery-Compat 3.0.0 package.
>   We recommend this version for most web sites, since it provides the
>   best compatibility for all website visitors.
> - If your web site is built only for evergreen leading-edge browsers, or
>   is an HTML-based app contained in a webview (for example PhoneGap or
>   Cordova) where you know which browser engines are in use, go for the
>   jQuery 3.0.0 package.
> - Until we announce otherwise, both packages will contain the same
>   public APIs in correspondingly-numbered major and minor versions. This
>   should make it easy for developers to switch between the two and be
>   maximally compatible with third-party jQuery plugins.

Reference: https://blog.jquery.com/2014/10/29/jquery-3-0-the-next-generations/

Comment: Note for ASP.NET 4.0 users: jQuery 3.x breaks postback.  https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-jquery-3-0-runs-in-strict-mode

Comment: If you need to support older browsers like Internet Explorer 6-8, Opera 12.1x or Safari 5.1+, use jQuery 1.#  (source: http://jquery.com/browser-support/)

Comment: Is this answer really accurate? As far as I've learned jQuery Compat 3.0 isn't even available in more than an alpha version.

Comment: @HischT References are provided with the answer. The part you're talking about is even litterly copied from jQuery's own blog post about this. I don't know how accurate you want it to be, but I can assure it won't get any better than having the source as a reference. Also, look at the date of this answer. That was more than 2 years ago. I do my best to keep this updated with relevant information regarding new releases, but that's pretty much it. If you feel improvements can be made, edit the answer and get it under review by me or the community.

Comment: @icecub Please note that my comment was formulated as a question and not as a true fact, because I'm not 100% certain about it. I just tried to download or even find any info about jQuery Compat 3 and cant find any more info than that blog post you're referring to, and an additional alpha version of it. To me it seems they ditched jQuery Compat 3 just before launch. If anyone can prove me wrong I'll be very happy since I'd love to use jQuery Compat 3 in my project.

Comment: Jquery-compat was cancelled prior to release in early 2016 after MS dropped support for IE8-10. https://blog.jquery.com/2016/01/14/jquery-3-0-beta-released/