# DataTables doesn't work in IE-8/below

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I am using `DataTables` to display the data in a tabular form with some pagination and sorting. It is working perfectly fine in all browsers but in IE it doesn't work in 8 and below versions. According to the documentations [here](https://datatables.net/download/compatibility) it should work form IE-6+.

The way I tested it, by just pressing the F12 key and change the browser versions. Not sure if this is the right way to test it but I would like to know if anyinw has faced the same issue. I am using the following CDNs. Please let me know if this is the right way to test `Datatables` in different versions of IE.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.css">  
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/pagination/input.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you really needing to support IE8 and below?

Comment: My main concern is what if someone uses IE8 or below and in that case the user would just see the plain table without any Datatables features. I need at least IE8.

Comment: I would start by testing in a real IE8 browser, so that you are not fooled by artifacts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **jQuery** issue, not a dataTables issue...Downgrade your jQuery version from `3.2.1` to [**`1.2.x`**](https://code.jquery.com/jquery/#jquery-all-1.x) or below, and it will work.

The current jQuery version (`3.2.1`) [does only support IE 9+](https://jquery.com/browser-support/). Support for 6-8 [was actually dropped already in 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41605459/1407478).

Personally I use **1.9.1** in all my projects. I Have no problems with older browsers or any mobile devices or tablets. I use latest version of dataTables along with latest Angular `1.x`. If you not have any particular reason for using jQuery `2.x` or `3.x`, then `1.9.1` is as good as any version.