# Performance difference between different versions of jQuery

Tags: jquery, performance

I am currently using jquery 1.11.3 on my websites

The first is usable only on our local network so on google chrome and google chrome android

The second is for our customers, they may use internet explorer

I would like to know the difference of performance between the different versions
And if I have to change version of jquery?

Thank you

Comment: Your question is far too broad for SO. That said, if you take the time to Google your question, this is the first hit: https://jsperf.com/speed-comparison-of-jquery-versions/31

Comment: useful link for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41605120/what-is-the-difference-with-jquery-version-1-version-2-and-version-3-versions-r

Comment: Rory McCrossan I have already searched, that's why I ask the question, there is no jquery 3 on the site

Comment: @Rocstar you have the ability to amend the test to include it yourself...

Comment: On this site is a small benchmark test of all three version, which compares "executing per seconds" for a specific task: [JQuery version speed test](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/2838/0/jquery-version-speed-test)