# Run JavaScript/AJAX only after a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Right now, my script executes right after page load, and then again after button click. Is it possible to make the script idle/wait until I click the button, and THEN run? To my understanding, this code is asynchronous, which is fine, but I don't want it to run as soon as the page loads.

I have a simple HTML button:

```
<button type="submit">Log in</button>
```

And here's my script:

```
var myButton = document.querySelector('button'); //I realize theres an easier jQuery for this
var token;

function getToken(){

        alert("get token");
        var settings = {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": "...",
            "method": "POST",
            "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "cache-control": "no-cache"
            },
            "processData": false,
            "data": "{  \r\n\"Username\":\"username123\",\r\n\"Password\":\"password123\"\r\n}"
        }           
        alert("going to ajax");
        return $.ajax(settings);                        
        }       

function handleData(data){

        console.log(data);          
        token = data.access_token;
        console.log(token);
    }

getToken().done(handleData);

myButton.onclick = function(e){         
            e.preventDefault();
            getToken();                     
    }
```

I have implemented some alerts to visualize the flow. It goes like this:

1. Load page
2. Alert: "get token"
3. Alert: "going to ajax"
4. Console: data and token
5. Button appears
6. I click the button
7. step 2-4 repeats

Comment: Stop calling it before the button click then--what do you imagine `getToken().done(whatever)` is doing?

Comment: you want it to run on button click but you are calling the function here `getToken().done(handleData);`

Comment: Yeah, I realized my stupid mistake now. Thanks for opening my eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling your function when the page loads with `getToken().done(handleData);`. Move it inside your button click event handler instead of `getToken()`.

**CODE:**

```
var myButton = document.querySelector('button'); //I realize theres an easier jQuery for this
var token;

function getToken(){

        alert("get token");
        var settings = {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": "...",
            "method": "POST",
            "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "cache-control": "no-cache"
            },
            "processData": false,
            "data": "{  \r\n\"Username\":\"username123\",\r\n\"Password\":\"password123\"\r\n}"
        }           
        alert("going to ajax");
        return $.ajax(settings);                        
        }       

function handleData(data){

        console.log(data);          
        token = data.access_token;
        console.log(token);
    }



myButton.onclick = function(e){         
            e.preventDefault(); 
            getToken().done(handleData);                    
    }
```

Comment: you are caling `getToken()` twice

Comment: I tried so many work arounds before finally deciding to ask here, and it was this simple?? I feel so dumb right now. Anyways, thank you for spotting this when I couldn't. getToken(); inside the onclick is also unnecessary now.

Answer (score 1):

use `jQuery` selectors instead of `var myButton = document.querySelector('button');`. Give your button an id `id="loginBtn"` and use it as selector like the following.

```js
    function getToken() {

      alert("get token");
      var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "...",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "cache-control": "no-cache"
        },
        "processData": false,
        "data": "{  \r\n\"Username\":\"username123\",\r\n\"Password\":\"password123\"\r\n}"
      }
      alert("going to ajax");
      return $.ajax(settings);
    }

    function handleData(data) {

      console.log(data);
      token = data.access_token;
      console.log(token);
    }

    $('#loginBtn').on('click', () => {
      getToken()
        .done(handleData)
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="loginBtn" type="submit">Log in</button>
```

Comment: I agree it looks a lot cleaner with jQuery. Is there a difference between your jQuery link and this one which I'm currently using?: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js first thing I notice is that the version number is different.

Comment: Yes, there are some minor differences you can read more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41605120/what-is-the-difference-with-jquery-version-1-version-2-and-version-3-versions-r

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<button class="a class" id="a id" onclick="function"></button>
```

Plus, can you vote me? I joined yesterday and my questions are rated -7.

: (

Comment: That will not change anything sadly. I'm pretty sure the same as myButton.onclick = function() which I already have.

Comment: only html and css

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before(but this is by no means a good practice) But you could just have an empty script tag, and change the src of the script tag with

```
document.getElementById("script").src="thing.js";
```

when the button is pressed.
I can't really see where this could possibly have been called before the button was pressed, could you not just use the onClick="" attribute to call the function?

Finally, you could create one with document.createElement but that's better to google than for me to explain it.

Comment: Ok, this doesn't make sense

Comment: is this better?